# param is missing or the value is empty laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, http, integration

I am creating a user with the api provided. I am using Laravel and trying to store data to smartrmail and docs to create new subscriber is here https://docs.smartrmail.com/en/articles/636615-list-subscribers
Each time i send request i get following error:

```
Server error: `POST https://go.smartrmail.com/api/v1/lists/1sptso/list_subscribers` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response: {"error":"param is missing or the value is empty: subscribers"}
```

{"error":"param is missing or the value is empty: subscribers"}

I am using Laravel and my code is here

```
Route::get('smartrmail',function(){

    $headers = [
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'token f91715d5-3aac-4db3-a133-4b3a9493a9a4',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    ];
    
    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
        'headers' => $headers
    ]);
    $data = [
        "subscribers"=>[
            [
                "email"=> "vanhalen@example.com",
                "first_name"=> "van",
                "last_name"=> "halen",
                "subscribed"=> true,
            ]
        ]
    ];
    $res = $client->request('POST', 'https://go.smartrmail.com/api/v1/lists/1sptso/list_subscribers', [
    
        'form_params' => [
                $data 
                       
            ]

    ]);
    return($res);
    // echo $res->getStatusCode();
});
```

Anybody help me to figure out what is wrong here. I am following this docs
https://docs.smartrmail.com/en/articles/636615-list-subscribers
to create a new subscriber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```php
'form_params' => [
    $data
]
```

use

```php
'json' => $data
```

#### Explanation

You want to send `json` data (I assume that because you set header `'Content-Type' => 'application/json'`, which means that you are sending json), but `form_params` is used for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

`json` sets header to `application/json` and sends data as `json`.

As you set proper header, this should work too:

```php
'body' => $data
```

Proper name of param you can find in Guzzle docs, I used [uploading data](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#uploading-data) part.

Comment: Hi, thanks it worked. can you tell me why not form_params but json

Comment: I've updated answer with explanation. Hope I did it well :)